# Posting form data to URL and taking user to the URL (PHP and HTML)

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" class="txt" value="Account" />
    <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" class="txt" value="Password" />
  <div class="alignleft">
    <a href="#">Forgot?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="alignright">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login" value="Login" />
  </div>
```

This form will log people into their control panel (we hold no sensitive data and we know there are better ways to login) but anyway they are not in a database, they login by simply following a URL like this:

www.example.com/user?user=USERNAME?pwrd=PASSWORD

So is the user follows that URL replacing the user and password with their own it will log them in.

How can I make my HTML form post the data to a URL and take them to the URL when they click submit?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have 2 ? in a url query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<form action="yoururl.com/url" method="get">`
That uses a query string for the form submission.

Comment: Thanks! so how would I append both the username and password, mid URL not just at the end?

Comment: What do you mean? In your example, they're at the end.

Comment: ah yes sorry they are at the end but there is stuff between them the actual URL looks like this:  http://www.example.com/logincheck.asp?acct=USER&pwd=PASS

Comment: so how can I get the &pwd= between the username and password?

Comment: I still really have no idea what you mean. You can add additional inputs of type hidden if you want constant variables in the query string, though.